Peripheral subgroup determined up to conjugation
Let $K$ be an oriented knot in $S^3$, let $X_K := S^3 - \mathrm{int} \ N(K)$ be its knot exterior and let $i: \partial X_K \hookrightarrow X_K$ be the subspace inclusion. The peripheral subgroup is the subgroup generated by a meridian $m$ (a simple closed curve in $\partial X_K$ nullhomologous in $N(K)$ but not in $\partial N(K)$) and a longitude $l$ (a simple closed curve in $\partial N(K)$ which is nullhomologous in $X_K$ but not in $\partial N(K)$). These two curves are unique up to isotopy on $\partial N(K)$.

Q1: According to e.g. Burde-Zieschang p.40, the homotopy classes of the pair $(m,l)$ are uniquely determined in $\pi_1 X_K$ up to a common conjugating element. Why is that?


Q2: Similarly, Burde-Zieschang claims that the peripheral subgroup only defines a class of conjugate subgroup in $\pi_1 X_K$. Why? In particular: the peripheral subgroup is exactly the same thing as $i_* (\pi_1 \partial X_K)$, which is a well-defined subgroup of $\pi_1 X_K$ (this is e.g. Rolfsen's approach). Then why do Burde and Zieschang claim that only the class of conjugate subgroup is well-defined?

I suspect there might be an issue with the basepoint, but since the meridian and longitude can be taken to intersect in a unique point in $\partial X_K$, taking this point as the basepoint should not lead to the conjugacy issue.

Yes, this is a basepoint issue. Presumably, the authors do not want to use a particular choice of a basepoint. That's all.
